# Callback in Outbound Gateway Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, enterprise-integration

I need to callback request after output of otbound gateway . My components :
Input Message -> Service Activator ->webservice OutBound Gateway -> Response Message

here I need to check response message and supply new message as input message which depends upon response code.

[image: Here is my configuration which i tried]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear; you should show the configuration you have tried.

You can simply add a reply channel to the gateway and add more processing after that channel.

Comment: I'm using some webservices which return some response message through reply channel of ws-outbound gateway , I'm reading these response on a service activator if getting some error code on that message I want to make a callback with a new message.

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking - "make a callback" - callback to what?. You can do anything you want on the reply channel flow - add a router to take different actions based on the result; etc; etc.